# Setting tableFooterView hides empty cell divider lines

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to set the  tableFooterView to display a view that contains ads.

When I do this then I will lose the nice dividers that show up in the empty cells after the table has ended.

Is there any way to reenable the dividers / is there a better place to put this view?  If I simply add it to the view then the table will not have an extra bit of space at the bottom and some of the rows will be hidden by my ads (which I don't want).

Comment: It's probably a better idea to just anchor it to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I could but I don't want to have to resize the UITableView if I can help it.

Comment: How come? What kind of data is the table displaying? Could we see a screenshot?

Comment: How about using section footer?